# How do you iteratively develop with docker?

Tags: python, docker

How does one iteratively develop their app using Docker? I have only just started using it and my workflow is very slow, so I'm pretty sure I'm using it wrong.

I'm following along with a python machine learning course on Youtube, and so I am using Docker to work with python 3. I know I can use virtualenv or a VM, but I want to learn Docker as well so bear with me.

My root directory looks like so:

```
Dockerfile  main.py*
```

My docker file:

```
FROM python
COPY . /src
RUN pip install quandl
RUN pip install pandas
CMD ["python", "/src/main.py"]
```

And the Python file:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import quandl

print("Hello world from main.py")

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")

print("getting data frame for WIKI/GOOGL")
print(df.head())
```

My workflow has been:

1. Learn something new from the tutorial
2. Update python file
3. Build the docker image: `docker build -t myapp .`
4. Run the app: `docker run my app python /src/main.py`

Questions:

1. How can I speed this all up? For every change I want to try, I end up rebuilding. This causes pip to get dependencies each time which takes way too long.
2. Instead of editing a python file and running it, how might a get an interactive shell from the python version running in the container?
3. If I wanted my program to write out a file, how could I get this file back to my local system from the container after the program has finished?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I should add, this was the tutorial I was following in general to run some python code in Docker: https://www.civisanalytics.com/blog/using-docker-to-run-python/

Comment: For development you can mount a local folder as a volume into the container. Use the argument `-v /full/path/to/dir:/dir/in/container:rw` for your `docker run`. There are other option as `rw` (read/write) as well. Use `docker restart` to restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Speeding up the rebuild process

The simplest thing you can do is reorder your Dockerfile.

```
FROM python
RUN pip install quandl
RUN pip install pandas
COPY . /src
CMD ["python", "/src/main.py"]
```

The reason this helps is that Docker will re-use the cached build for commands it has already run. Now when you rebuild after modifying your source code, it will re-use the build results for the `pip` commands, as they do not need to be run again. It will only run the `COPY` step.

### Getting a python shell

You can exec a shell in the **running** container and run your python command.

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
python <...>
```

Or, you can run a container with *just a shell*, and skip running your app entirely (then, run it however you want).

```
docker run -it <image> bash
python <...>
```

### Writing outside the container

Mount an external directory into the container. Then write to the mounted path.

```
docker run -v /local/path:/path <.. rest of command ..>
```

Then when you write in the container to `/path/file`, the file will show up outside the container at `/local/path/file`.

Comment: I would combine the `pip install` commands, personally, rather than two layers

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think this approach is flawed in that it doesn't ensure that someone else who builds from this dockerfile will get the same versions of libraries. i.e. it doesn't create a reproducible build.